# Passing sed command line string to bash as variable

Tags: bash, variables, sed

I have a bash script which uses one multi-line sed command to change a file. **From the command line**, this line works:

```
sed -e '1a\' -e '/DELIMITER="|" \' -e '/RESTRICT_ADD_CHANGE=1 \' -e '/FIELDS=UPDATE_MODE|PRIMARYKEYVALUE|PATRONFLAGS' -e '1 d' general_update_01 > general_update_01.mp
```

I use the same bash script for a variety of files. So I need to pass all of the sed commands from the sending application to the bash script as a single parameter. However, when it passes in from the application, I get only -e.

In the bash script, I have tried a variety of ways to receive the variable as a complete string. None of these store the variable.

```
sed_instructions=$(echo $6)
sed_instructions=$6
sed_instructions=$(eval "$6")
```

and a few other configurations.

My command line would use the variable like this:

```
sed $sed_instructions $filename > $filename.mp
```

Comment: You don't show how you invoke your bash script.

Comment: "I need to pass all of the sed commands [...] as a single parameter" -- why do you think that?

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is relevant: *I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!*

Answer (score 3):

I assume you invoke your shell script like this

```sh
script.sh -e '1a' -e '/DELIMITER="|" ' -e '/RESTRICT_ADD_CHANGE=1 ' -e '/FIELDS=UPDATE_MODE|PRIMARYKEYVALUE|PATRONFLAGS' -e '1 d' general_update_01
```

What you want to do here is store the *nth* parameter as the filename, and the first n-1 parameters **in an array**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env

n=$#
filename=${!n}
sed_commands=("${@:1:n-1}")

# Now, call sed
sed "${sed_commands[@]}" "$filename" > "${filename}.mp"
```

---

To demonstrate that code in action:

```sh
$ set -- one two three four
$ n=$#
$ filename=${!n}
$ args=("${@:1:n-1}")
$ declare -p filename args
declare -- filename="four"
declare -a args=([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three")
```